# Homologous curves and maps to surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Say I have two smooth one-cycles $Z, Z'$ on a 3-manifold $M$, i.e. just formal linear combinations of (let us say disjoint) smooth circles.  Assume they're homologous.

> Is there a map to a surface $\pi: M \to S$ and homologous zero-cycles $P, P'$ on the surface such that $\pi$ is a submersion over $P, P'$ and one has $\pi^{-1}(P) = Z$ and $\pi^{-1}(P') = Z'$?

Comment: If each component of $Z, Z'$ has multiplicity 1, then I suspect that such a map exists to $S^2$, with $P,P'$ single points. The corank obstruction doesn't exist in this case, and I think it's likely such a map can be constructed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the answer to this question is no in general.

Suppose $Z$ has two components $Z_1 \cup Z_2$ with different multiplicities (as a formal linear combination of knots) and $Z'$ has one component. Then $P$ must have  two points $P=\{p_1,p_2\}$ (ignoring multiplicity), and $P'$ one $P'=\{p'\}$. Then $\pi_1(M-(Z\cup Z'))$ surjects a free group of rank at least two (the meridians of $Z_i$ go to loops about $p_i$, which must generate a subgroup of $\pi_1(S-(P\cup P'))$ of rank at least two).

The *corank* of a group is the largest rank of a free group that it surjects. It is known that there are 3-manifold groups with [arbitrarily large $b_1$ and corank 1.](http://msp.org/gt/2002/6-1/p15.xhtml) What is needed to get a counterexample to your question is a manifold with 3 torus boundary components which has fundamental group of corank 1, and satisfying an appropriate homological condition. I feel like a construction of the sort that Shelly Harvey carries out ought to have the right properties.

**Addendum:** I looked at a paper of [Leininger-Reid](http://msp.org/agt/2002/2-1/p04.xhtml), which gives an example of a compact 3-manifold $M$ with hyperbolic interior, 4 boundary components, and cut number 1. From this, one can get an example which answers your question in the negative. By half-lives, half-dies, there is an oriented surface $\Sigma\subset M$ which is homologically non-trivial in $H_2(M, \partial M)$, and intersects each boundary component in consistently oriented parallel non-trivial curves (in particular, non-empty). Now, perform Dehn fillings on each boundary component so that the intersection number with $\partial \Sigma$ are different to get a manifold $N$. Partition the cores of the Dehn fillings into $Z$ and $Z'$, with multiplicity determined by the intersection number of $\partial \Sigma$ with the meridian of each Dehn filling, and orienting the components of $Z'$ opposite to the induced orientation of $\partial \Sigma$. This gives the desired pair of cycles which are homologous and which cannot be induced by pullback from 0-cycles on a surface because the link complement has cut number 1.

Comment: Cool..........!

Comment: also: what if I asked instead about the equivalence relation generated by such maps to surfaces --- does the above example also show this is finer than homology?

Comment: @VivekShende: I don't think this example shows this, because to get transitivity, one may have to take a sequence of cycles and maps to surfaces. I don't see immediately how to show this gives the same as homology however.